# Arrays: replace values with values from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have

```
$Array1 = [3=>'dog', 7=>'cat', 9=>'duck', 10=>'dog', 11=>'dog'];
$Array2 = ['cat'=>'sofa', 'dog'=>'kennel', 'duck'=>'pond'];
```

I want the output $ArrayOut where

```
$ArrayOut = [3=>'kennel', 7=>'sofa', 9=>'pond', 10=>'kennel', 11=>'kennel'];
```

I can do this easily through a `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($Array1 as $key => $value) {
    $ArrayOut[$key] = $Array2[$value];
}
```

but I was thinking if I could avoid a loop and use a combination of inbuilt PHP array functions to create the same output.

Any clue would be helpful thanks.

Comment: What is your logic toward trying achieving this array result? Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Is there any pattern to your merging of these arrays?

Comment: The pattern is that the values of the first array is to be used as keys in the second array to find the replacement values.

Comment: I dont think there is a single build-in function to do this.
But you can easily loop through the first array and fill a third array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does the trick.

```
$Array1 = [3=>'dog', 7=>'cat', 9=>'duck', 10=>'dog', 11=>'dog'];
$Array2 = ['cat'=>'sofa', 'dog'=>'kennel', 'duck'=>'pond'];

$ArrayOut = array_map(function($v) use($Array2){
    return $Array2[$v];
}, $Array1);
print_r($ArrayOut);
//Array ( [3] => kennel [7] => sofa [9] => pond [10] => kennel [11] => kennel )
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't (currently) a native function for this exact task.  Using `array_map()` will require a user-function to be used. One benefit of functional-style iteration is that it reduces the number of global variables. Otherwise use a classic loop and modify the input array's values by reference.  If any given value is not represented as key in the lookup array, then the null coalescing operator will just use the original value in the assignment.  This avoids Notices without making any iterated function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TdNtr))

```
$array = [3 => 'dog', 7 => 'cat', 9 => 'duck', 10 => 'dog', 11 => 'dog'];

$lookup = ['cat' => 'sofa', 'dog' => 'kennel', 'duck' => 'pond'];

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = $lookup[$value] ?? $value;
}

var_export($array);
```

Code >=PHP7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jmHOS))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => $lookup[$v] ?? $v, $array)
);
```

Both Output:

```
array (
  3 => 'kennel',
  7 => 'sofa',
  9 => 'pond',
  10 => 'kennel',
  11 => 'kennel',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I have missread the purpose. Your best bet would be to work a foreach array in my opinion.

I'll still leave my answer here for future reference, if someone requires matching values from one array to keys of another array

There is something you can use, as long as your arrays are in the order you want.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

array_keys will extract into an array, the keys of a specified array

array_values will extract into an array, the values of specified array

array_combine will, as the function says, combine into an array the match arguments - being the first array argument the keys and the second the values.

Comment: The second array is like a dictionary. The first array's length is variable and may not be equal to the length of the second array.

Comment: Obviously, but your not answering the OP question.

Comment: Your code doesn't works with given input data outputs. Even if input arrays have same length, it will outputs : `[3=>'sofa',...]` instead of `[3=>'kennel',...]`.

Comment: You're right, I missread the question. Thought the output would be the merging of one's keys with one's values. edited, thanks and sorry

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$Array1 = [3=>'dog', 7=>'cat', 9=>'duck'];
$Array2 = ['cat'=>'sofa', 'dog'=>'kennel', 'duck'=>'pond'];
# Flip the array
$new = array_flip($Array1);
# Replace the values
$new2 = array_replace($Array2, $new);
# This step you would lose the duplicates
$n = array_combine(array_merge($new2, $new), $Array2);
print_r($n);
```

Ouptut:

```
Array
(
    [7] => sofa
    [3] => kennel
    [9] => pond
)
```

Comment: This unexplained answer damages array data that may have duplicate values.